# Loose coupling and class creation

Tags: oop

I went trough many tutorials and blogs about OOP principles.
As I understand loose coupling and writing testable classes, there is one thing I hesitate about.

Let's say I have a Lake class.
The lake class has dependencies injected like weather and location (strategy pattern etc), but it creates classes that are returned, let's say fishes.

So function catch() returns Fish class.

Is it tight coupled, cause the fish class has a constructor which also needs to be "unit tested"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instantiate the Fish objects directly in the class like 
new Fish();
then there is a tight coupling between the two classes. If Fish is more than a simple Data Transfer Object (an object that only carries data and almost no logic at all), then I'd avoid such a tight coupling. 
There are several ways to solve this, for instance:

1. Inject an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) into the Lake that creates the Fish. So you can substitute the creation process.
2. Use an inversion of control container and ask it to create a fish for you. You can think of such a container as a configurable factory. The [Service Locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) is an approach that can be handy in this situation.

However, if Fish is only a simple DTO, it is questionable whether it is worth the effort in terms of complexity, readability and performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Markus, I'm using Service Locator Pattern at the moment.

Comment: Service locator is an anti-pattern unless you're writing a framework.